# Rspec, Devise, Factory girl - how to sign in Factory user through Rspec controller test?

Tags: rspec, controller, devise, factory-bot

I have a Posts controller and I have just installed Devise to add some authentication quickly and easily. Before I installed Devise, I had created some tests for the 'new' action of my Posts controller. After installing Devise, my tests were failing until i added the

```
config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
```

line to my spec_helper.rb  file.

I also have the line

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index]
```

in my PostsController.

Now when I run my tests, they all pass except these 2:

```
it "should be successful" do
     get :new
     response.should be_success
  end

  it "should have the right title" do
     get :new
     response.should have_selector('title', :content => @base_title + " | New post")
  end
```

I'm using Factory girl as well. The error is cause by the before_filter except parameter. I need to be able to sign in the user in rspec with a factory user. How do I sign the Factory user in from within the Rspec controller test? How do I define the Factory user?

I have tried this in my factories.rb:

```
Factory.define :user do |user|  
  user.name                  "Test User"
  user.email                 "user@example.com"
  user.password              "password"
  user.password_confirmation "password"
end
```

But then I get the error:

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `password_salt=' for #<User:0x00000103cac958>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I highly recommend removing your controller tests and using Cucumber stories instead -- RSpec is not as convenient for testing user-facing stuff as Cucumber is.

In Cucumber, you'd want to log in through the UI to mimic exactly what the user will do. I would tend to do the same thing in a controller spec, though some people might prefer mocking things out instead.

As for `undefined method password_salt=`, did you migrate your test DB?

Comment: ahhhh totally forgot to migrate the test DB...now i'm getting:            `Failure/Error: @user = create!(Factory(:user))
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email can't be blank, Password can't be blank`

Comment: What code is giving that error? (The error message should have a filename and line number.)

Comment: Thats a test in my Posts Controller `before(:each) do
         @user = create!(Factory(:user))
         test_sign_in(@user)
      end`

Comment: That should be `Factory :user`, not `create!(Factory(:user))`. `Factory` already creates the record.

Comment: Saying "it's not working", by itself, is useless. What's the error now? What does your code look like now?

Comment: PostsController test......`describe "GET 'new'" do
      before(:each) do
         @user = Factory :user
      end
      it "should be successful" do
         get :new
         response.should be_success
      end end`   .....factories.rb.....`Factory.define :user do |user|
   user.name                  "Test User"
   user.email                 "user@example.com"
   user.password              "password"
   user.password_confirmation "password"

end`

Comment: ......Error......  GET 'new' should be successful
     Failure/Error: @user = Factory :user
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `name=' for #<User:0x00000102e42d90>`

Comment: OK. Look at the error message. It's telling you that `User#name=` is undefined. Once again, that probably means you forgot to migrate your test DB...

Comment: That was the first thing I tried after I saw the `User#name=` error...could it be an error in the controller?

Comment: I don't see how. Does your DB actually have a `name` field in the `users` table?

Comment: Ah no...man dumb mistakes...but now it says `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email has already been taken` and my factories.rb looks like this: `Factory.define :user do |user|
   
  
   user.email                 "user@example.com"
   user.password              "password"
   user.password_confirmation "password"
end`

Comment: Well, there you go. Do you understand the latest error? Do you understand what to do to fix it?

Comment: no im not sure what to do about the email...use a sequence? clear the database somehow?

Comment: A sequence would work well (actually, I'd probably use the ffaker gem).

Comment: Great! Why don't you choose this answer and/or upvote it, then?

Comment: I'll give you the check for now, don't quite have enough reputation points for the upvote ha