# Authenticated RSpec testing and Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, devise

I'm writing basic tests for a simple CRUD rails application. I am using devise for authentication and Factory Girl for object creation whilst testing, after testing I am clearing the test.db with the Database Cleaner gem.

I am testing a controller with RSpec but need an admin user to be signed in for this to be a 'true' test.

So far I have been following documentation but I don't believe it is working.

I have a test which checks if the count has been changed by one:

```
     describe "POST create" do
      context "with valid attributes" do
       it "creates a new room" do
        expect{ post :create, room: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:room) }.to change(Room,:count).by(1)
       end
```

When I run the test suite I get the error:

> expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0

From reading around it seems I need to setup authentication with my tests. To do this I have created relevant Factories:

```
  # Devise User Class
  factory :user do
   email "basicuser@mvmanor.co.uk"
   password "u"
   password_confirmation "u"
   admin false
   customer false
  end

 # Admin
 factory :admin, class: User do
  email "basicadmin@mvmanor.co.uk"
  password "a"
  password_confirmation "a"
  admin true
  customer false
 end
```

I have also created the relevant Devise mappings macros:

```
 module UserControllerMacros
  def login_admin
   before(:each) do
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:admin]
    sign_in FactoryGirl.create(:admin) # Using factory girl as an example
   end
  end

  def login_user
   before(:each) do
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    sign_in FactoryGirl.create(:user) # Using factory girl as an example
   end
  end
end
```

I'm not sure if I'm heading in the right direction with this. I certainly need my controller tests to be authenticated.

Comment: I don't know if password length has anything to do with this issue, I think the minimum Device password length is 8 (you can change in config/initializers/devise.rb file)    # Range for password length.
  config.password_length = 8..72

Comment: How do you use the macros (please show relevant code)

Comment: @jyrkim Forgot to mention I set the password length to 1 whilst testing.

Comment: okay, good luck :-) I'm no specialist in RSpec test - if I was then I could try to give an advice.

Comment: Here is a link to the Ruby on Rails tutorial code at GitHub, it's not identical but there is FactoryGirl applied. https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4/blob/master/spec/models/micropost_spec.rb I hope you find it useful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rspec, Devise, Factory girl - how to sign in Factory user through Rspec controller test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301434/rspec-devise-factory-girl-how-to-sign-in-factory-user-through-rspec-controll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the first `describe` statement add this:

```
let!(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
before { subject.stub(current_user: admin, authenticate_user!: true) }
```

it should stub your authentication.

And one little trick for your happiness: add in your `spec_helper.rb` anywhere within

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
...
end
```

block this code:

```
config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
```

and now you don't need to preface all factory_girl methods with `FactoryGirl`, so instead of `FactoryGirl.create` you can write just `create`.

Comment: Ah didn't know that about the Syntax::Methods, that's pretty cool. Was really stuck with this!